# Filter/de-duplicate repeated variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add functionality into my JS script that de-duplicates the values returned. My original script here:

```js
try{
var productList = dataLayer.basket.products.map(function(product) {
    return product.travelType;
});

return productList.join('|');
  }
catch(err){}
```

which returns values from an array like `Bus|Bus|Train|Car|Bus`

What I am trying to get to is an additional part of the script that would clean those values and de-duplicate them. For example the above script would only show "bus" once e.g. `Bus|Train|Car`

I have tried to do this using a filter but I am getting a null value being returned:

```js
try{
var productList = dataLayer.basket.products.map(function(product) {
    return product.travelType;
});
  
var filteredArray = productList.filter(function(item, pos){
    return productList.indexOf(item)=== pos;
  });
  
return filteredArray.join('|');
  }
catch(err){}
```

Any guidance would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks,
M

Comment: You have a return statement but no context for it - is this all inside a function?

Comment: it would be helpful to see the entire function that is returning a null value.

Answer (score 1):

To filter duplicates in an array:

```js
const array = ['toto', 'tata', 'tutu', 'toto'];
const filteredArray = [...new Set(array)];

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const remove_duplicates = (arr) => {
    let setArr = new Set(arr);
    let values = setArr.values();
    return Array.from(values);
}
const example = ['Bus', 'Bus', 'Car', 'Bike'];

console.log(remove_duplicates(example).join('|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates) is just what you're searching for. Just apply that to your productList and it should get rid of all duplicate values.

Edit: oops, I just saw you were already doing exaclty that. But your code should work that way, I just tried it out in the console and it worked just as expected. The null values must be caused by some other part of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine as is, the error must be in your data or in another part of your code that you didn't post:

```js
const dataLayer = {
  basket:{products:[
      {travelType:'a'},
      {travelType:'b'},
      {travelType:'c'},
      {travelType:'b'},
      {travelType:'c'},
      {travelType:'a'},

  ]}
}

var productList = dataLayer.basket.products.map(function(product) {
  return product.travelType;
});
  
var filteredArray = productList.filter(function(item, pos){
  return productList.indexOf(item)=== pos;
});
  
console.log(filteredArray.join('|'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using modern javascript:

```
let arr = ['Bus', 'Bus', 'Train', 'Car', 'Bus'];
let filteredArr= [... new Set(arr)]; 
let result = filteredArr.join('|');
```